# .NET TopologySuite & ProjNet problem with LineString length calculation

Tags: nettopologysuite

I have below code in order to compute distance from A(60.054166, -35.542222) to B(-48.175833, -8.541111).
Above coordinates are in EPSG:4326 system (which is the standard GPS Lat/Lon coordinates).

Default **unit of measure is angle**, so **I transform everything to EPSG:3857 where unit of measure is meter**.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

        /* we will convert everything from 4326 (lat/lon) to 3857 since the latter's default unit is meters instead of rads */

        geomFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(1e6), 3857);

        var cs4326 = ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84;
        var cs3857 = ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WebMercator;
        var ctFactory = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.CoordinateTransformationFactory();
        var ct = ctFactory.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(cs4326, cs3857);
        var mt = ct.MathTransform;

        var p1 = new double[] { -35.5422222, 60.054166 };
        var p2 = new double[] { -8.541111, -48.1758333 };

        var r1 = mt.Transform(p1);
        var r2 = mt.Transform(p2);

        var lineString = geomFactory.CreateLineString(new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(r1[0], r1[1]), new Coordinate(r2[0], r2[1]) });
        Console.WriteLine("Distance is: " + lineString.Length / 1000 + " km.");
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output I get is:  **14,855.22 km but google maps measure tool outputs 12,343.32 for the same coordinates**.

Something tells me that Google's output is the correct one, so question is what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting the library more closely I've jumped into NetTopologySuite/src/NetTopologySuite/Algorithm/Length.cs

```
using System;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
namespace NetTopologySuite.Algorithm {

/// <summary>
/// Functions for computing length.
/// </summary>
/// <author>
/// Martin Davis
/// </author>
public class Length
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Computes the length of a <c>LineString</c> specified by a sequence of points.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pts">The points specifying the <c>LineString</c></param>
    /// <returns>The length of the <c>LineString</c></returns>
    public static double OfLine(CoordinateSequence pts)
    {
        // optimized for processing CoordinateSequences
        int n = pts.Count;
        if (n <= 1)
            return 0.0;

        double len = 0.0;

        var p = pts.GetCoordinateCopy(0);
        double x0 = p.X;
        double y0 = p.Y;

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            pts.GetCoordinate(i, p);
            double x1 = p.X;
            double y1 = p.Y;
            double dx = x1 - x0;
            double dy = y1 - y0;

            len += Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

            x0 = x1;
            y0 = y1;
        }
        return len;
    }

}}
```

It's now pretty obvious why I have such as huge deviation from google calculation.
It's using Euclidean distance and I suspect Google's using Haversine Formula.

If I add an extension method for LineString as such

```
public static class NetTopologySuiteGeometriesExtension
{

    public static double ToRadians(this double degrees)
    {
        double radians = (Math.PI / 180) * degrees;
        return (radians);
    }

    
    public static double HaversineDistance(this LineString s)
    {
        // optimized for processing CoordinateSequences
        var cs = s.CoordinateSequence;
        int n = cs.Count;
        if (n <= 1)
            return 0.0;

        double len = 0.0;

        var p = cs.GetCoordinateCopy(0);
        double x0 = p.X;
        double y0 = p.Y;

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            cs.GetCoordinate(i, p);
            double x1 = p.X;
            double y1 = p.Y;
            double dx = x1 - x0;
            double dy = y1 - y0;

            double R = 6371000;
            var lat = dx.ToRadians();
            var lng = dy.ToRadians();
            var h1 = Math.Sin(lat / 2) * Math.Sin(lat / 2) +
                          Math.Cos(x0.ToRadians()) * Math.Cos(x1.ToRadians()) *
                          Math.Sin(lng / 2) * Math.Sin(lng / 2);
            var h2 = 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Min(1, Math.Sqrt(h1)));
            len += R * h2;

            x0 = x1;
            y0 = y1;
        }
        return len;
    }
}
```

Then if I change

```
Console.WriteLine("Distance is: " + lineString.Length / 1000 + " km.");
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine("Distance is: " + lineString.HaversineDistance() / 1000 + " km.");
```

I get 12,212.01 km. which is close to Google and makes some sense.

Not a very "universal" solution, more of a dirty workaround - *if it is correct that is*.